# Array action is done on original array, not on copy

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
@array_a = ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
```

I want `@array_b` to be like `@array_a` but without the first two elements ,and `@array_a` to remain as is. I assigned the first array to a second array, and removed some elements there:

```
@array_b = @array_a
@array_b.shift
@array_b.shift
```

Both `@array_a` and `@array_b` miss the first two elements:

```
[85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
```

How can I let `@array_a` be unchanged after manipulating `@array_b`?

Comment: To retrieve a copy starting at index 2 use `@array_b = @array_a[2..-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`Object#dup`** here

**`dup` copies object by value not by reference**

```
    @array_a = ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]

    O/P  => ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]

    @array_b = @array_a.dup

    O/P  => ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]

    @array_b.shift
    @array_b.shift

    @array_b:

    O/P => [85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]

    @array_a:

    O/P  => ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
```

**So, after you dup `@array_a` into `@array_b` and remove elements from `@array_b` the `@array_a` remianed same.**

Comment: Oooh, forgot about by reference... Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you. you can accept and vote my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `Array` object like so:

```
@array_b = Array.new(@array_a)
```

Ruby does not create a new **array object** instead reuse the same object while assigning to a variable:

```
@array_a = Array.new
@array_a = ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
#=> ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
@array_a.object_id
#=> 2062
@array_b = @array_a
#=> ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
@array_b.object_id
#=> 2062
```

That's why mutation on `@array_b` gets reflected in `@array_a` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this issue is to use the subscript operator to create a sub-array and assign it to `@array_b`

It looks like this:

```
@array_a = ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   nil]
# => ["total", nil, 85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]

@array_b = @array_a[2..-1]
# => [85.35, 85.97, 85.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil]
```

It creates a sub-array starting on the third element (index 2) and ending on the last element (index -1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use either Ruby methods dup or clone of the Class Object. Have a look at this page to see the difference :

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone